# Android Implement two fragments that have different behavior when keyboard appears

Tags: android, android-fragments, keyboard, android-edittext, android-softkeyboard

I have an activity which holds 2 fragments, `FacebookFragment` and `GoogleFragment`.

Now when activity is launched it launches `FacebookFragment`. When user presses a button on `FacebookFragment` the activity shows `GoogleFragment` which will be added in the container and the `GoogleFragment` has transparency so that the user can see the contents of `FacebookFragment`.

In the second fragment `GoogleFragment` I have an `EditText` that is at the bottom of the view and when the keyboard appears I want the `EditText` to be shown `above keyboard`.

But on the other hand I want that when the keyboard appears the view in `FacebookFragment` to **stay as it is and not to be scrolled or resized from the keyboard.**

What I have tried so far is that for the activity I have added in manifest:

`android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustNothing"`

and in FacebookFragment I have added:

`getActivity().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_NOTHING);`

in GoogleFragment I have added:

`getActivity().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE);`

But this isnt working for me but I had to try that.

I have tried some answers that I have found here in stackoverflow but I haven't found the right solution.

Any solution is welcomed!
Thanks

PS: Activity has one `FrameLayout` container and both fragments are added to the same container.